# Don't change the font of dialog with respect to windows dpi in mfc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a dialog which is of (355,99) dimensions it only have a menu and task bar so it is of small size. its display is fine in 100% dpi but on 125 % dpi some controls on task cut out. how to scale them according to dpi in the following function

```
void CMainFrame::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO FAR* lpMMI)
{
   CMDIFrameWnd::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
   lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(355,99); // set minimum size  
}
```

Comment: Clearly you *never* want to hard-code pixel amounts.  Dialogs are special, they don't use pixel values but dialog units.  Use MapDialogRect() to convert.

Comment: How to use MapDialogRect()? can you give me some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by my own so i am posting it for helping others. for my problem i have find the dpi of system and set the dialog size accordingly.
here is my code:

```
  void CMainFrame::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO FAR* lpMMI)  
  {
      CMDIFrameWnd::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
      HDC hdcScreen = ::GetDC(NULL);
      int iDPI = -1; // assume failure
      if (hdcScreen) 
      {
          iDPI = ::GetDeviceCaps(hdcScreen, LOGPIXELSX);
          ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
       }
       switch(iDPI)
       {
          case 96:
              lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(355,99);
              break;
          case 120:
              lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(360,115);
              break;
          case 144:
            lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(365,134);
            break;
           case 196:
             lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(370,150);
             break;
            default:
              lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize = CPoint(355,99);
              break;

        }
    }
```